# Using jQuery to run function against all elements of selector

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I'm working with ASP.NET validators and need to enable/disable them based on section visibility.

Here is example on how I disable specific validator:

```
// Disable validators for hidden sections
        window.ValidatorEnable($("*[id$='DriverName1RequiredFieldValidator']")[0], false);
```

My sections is divs and my validators all have id ending with "Validator".
I guess I can write selection like:

```
$("#mySectionId *[id$='Validator']")
```

I will get multiple elements. I can loop them and call function, but I wonder if there more elegant way to do this?

Comment: You just need to enable/disable them?

Comment: I need to run function I showed as example, this is ASP.NET java function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$("#mySectionId *[id$='Validator']").each(function(){
    window.ValidatorEnable(this, false);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The jQuery API has just what you need. Check out this function.

http://api.jquery.com/each/